# npm Gulp dependencies missing, even after running npm install

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, npm, gulp

I have a project that uses Gulp. I deployed my project onto my Ubuntu server and now want to compile the assets (which is all my gulpfile does at the moment). Having installed Node and npm I run `npm install` from my project's root to install the dependencies. The package.json reads as follows:

```
  ...},
  "devDependencies": {
    "bower": ">=1.3.12",
    "gulp": "^3.8.10",
    "gulp-concat": "^2.4.3",
    "gulp-less": "^2.0.1",
    "gulp-minify-css": "^0.4.3",
    "gulp-notify": "^2.2.0",
    "gulp-rename": "^1.2.0",
    "gulp-uglify": "^1.1.0"
  }...
```

Upon then inspecting the `node_modules` folder in my project root I can see directories for each of the dependencies indicating they were installed. However when I run `gulp` I get npm errors such as the below:

```
Error: Cannot find module 'through2'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
    at require (module.js:380:17)
```

These seem to be dependencies of the my project's dependencies (as they are not referenced in my gulpfile), but why hasn't npm installed them?

I can manually install each one as the error arises but I then get another similar error for the next missing dependency.

How can I solve this?

Comment: Not answering your question, but providing a suggestion: don't use your production server for asset compilation. Build assets locally and upload/rsync them as part of your deploy. You'll save yourself from headaches such as this **and** reduce the need to install & configure software in yet another environment.

Comment: What is your environment, npm & node versions?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The solution was to delete the `node_modules` folder and rerun `npm install`.

It looks like the initial install failed partially for some reason.

Comment: this ***worked*** unlike trying to run ```npm uninstall```.