# cannot find module through2 while installing gulp

Tags: module, compilation, command, gulp

Above errors come if i run gulp command.
I don't know what is happening in my code while i run gulp command.

```
module.js :339
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'through2'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:337:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:287:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:366:17)
    at require (module.js:385:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (E:\Project\wamp\www\gulpTest\node_modules\laravel-elixir\node_modules\gulp-notify\lib\extra_api.js:1:77)
    at Module._compile (module.js:435:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:442:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:311:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:366:17)
```

Gulpfile.js

```
    var gulp = require('gulp'),  
    less = require('gulp-less'),
    sass = require('gulp-sass'),
    minify = require('gulp-minify-css'),
    concat = require('gulp-concat'),
    uglify = require('gulp-uglify'),
    rename = require('gulp-rename'),
    notify = require('gulp-notify'),
    growl = require('gulp-notify-growl'),
    phpunit = require('gulp-phpunit');
 var paths = {  
    'dev': {
        'less': './resources/assets/less/',
        'js': './resources/assets/js/',
        'vendor': './resources/assets/vendor/'
    },
    'production': {
        'css': './public/assets/css/',
        'js': './public/assets/js/'
    }
};

/*
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 | Elixir Asset Management
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 |
 | Elixir provides a clean, fluent API for defining some basic Gulp tasks
 | for your Laravel application. By default, we are compiling the Less
 | file for our application, as well as publishing vendor resources.
 |
 */



// CSS
gulp.task('css', function() {  
  return gulp.src(paths.dev.less+'app.less')
    .pipe(less())
    .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.production.css))
    .pipe(minify({keepSpecialComments:0}))
    .pipe(rename({suffix: '.min'}))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.production.css));
});

// JS
gulp.task('js', function(){  
  return gulp.src([
      paths.dev.vendor+'jquery/dist/jquery.js',
      paths.dev.vendor+'bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js',
      paths.dev.js+'js'
    ])
    .pipe(concat('app.min.js'))
    .pipe(uglify())
    .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.production.js));
});

// PHP Unit
gulp.task('phpunit', function() {  
  var options = {debug: false, notify: true};
  return gulp.src('./tests/*.php')
    .pipe(phpunit('./vendor/bin/phpunit', options))

    .on('error', notify.onError({
      title: 'PHPUnit Failed',
      message: 'One or more tests failed.'
    }))

    .pipe(notify({
      title: 'PHPUnit Passed',
      message: 'All tests passed!'
    }));
});
gulp.task('watch', function() {  
  gulp.watch(paths.dev.less + '/*.less', ['css']);
  gulp.watch(paths.dev.js + '/*.js', ['js']);
  gulp.watch('./tests/*.php', ['phpunit']);
});
gulp.task('default', ['css', 'js', 'phpunit', 'watch']);
```

Above is the gulp file.
if i do with elixir only it to shows problem.Above is the gulp file.
if i do with elixir only it to shows problem.Above is the gulp file.
if i do with elixir only it to shows problem.

Comment: please post your gulp file

Comment: .. you are either missing a require() or you have not run `npm install` from the cli

Comment: you can try deleting your node_modules folder and install the npm modules again by npm install command.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29211763/npm-gulp-dependencies-missing-even-after-running-npm-install

Answer (score 2):

You should first make sure that `through2` is in your `package.json`. If it isn't, run `npm --save-dev through2`.

If it is in your `package.json` run `npm install` to make sure its pulled in.

If it is installed, check your `gulpfile.js` has `require('through2')` in it.