# NPM Install is not installing dependencies

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, npm, gulp, ushahidi

I'm attempting to install the Ushahidi V3 Client. I've been following [the install process](https://www.ushahidi.com/support/install-ushahidi#installing-on-linux) up until when I need to build the project from the source repo using **npm and gulp** - both of which I've had zero experience with. Whenever I run **sudo npm install** in the project directory, the process runs without complaints. However, when I run **npm ls** to verify that dependencies have been downloaded, I get a bunch of dependencies listed out as being **missing**.

How do I get npm to resolve all of these dependencies?

## System Details

**OS** Ubuntu 14.04 (Trusty) 
**Node JS** v0.12.9 
**NPM** v3.5.1

## What I've tried

- Removing *node_modules* folder and re-running **sudo npm install** as referenced in this SO answer for a similar question: 
   [npm Gulp dependencies missing, even after running npm install](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29211763/npm-gulp-dependencies-missing-even-after-running-npm-install)
- Uninstalling and reinstalling node and npm

Comment: You shouldn't use `sudo npm install` use `npm install` instead

Comment: If I don't use sudo I get an EACCES error asking me to retry as root

Comment: Which dependencies are listed as missing? Are they under `dependencies` or `devDependencies`?

Comment: Check [this](https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/fixing-npm-permissions)  out

Comment: @Trung thanks going through that tute now. Will see if it makes a difference.

Comment: @godfrzero looks like it's pretty close to all my dependencies, dev and otherwise.

Comment: @Trung it was a combination of running as sudo and not having the build-essentials installed Please submit and answer and I'll mark it as correct :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Strainy, as your research :D

> It was a combination of running as sudo and not having the build-essentials.

That's why you should **not** use `sudo npm`

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps:

1. try npm uninstall. and then try npm install.

Also If it still doesn't work.

Try:

```
npm install -g npm-install-missing
```

or

```
npm-install-missing
```

For further reading, click [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm-install-missing).